# How to clear Office Word 2007/2010 custom properties with XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath, openxml, word-2007

```
<xsl:template match="o:CustomDocumentProperties">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In word 2003, I am able to get the word's document 2003's custom properties with the xsl:template match statement above.

What is the syntax to use if I am working on office Word 2007 or 2010?

Comment: I think this question is equivalent to "What is the XML element used for a document's custom properties in Word 2007 or 2010?", and thus it's not so much an xslt or xpath question but an OOXML (WordML) question, regarding the XML vocabulary. Looking at the 3rd Edition Part 1 at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm I don't see anything about custom properties in WordML. But I'm not experienced in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom document properties are maintained under a `Properties` element and use the following namespace:

```
http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties
```

An example of a custom property for Telephone Number:

```
<pkg:part pkg:name="/docProps/custom.xml"
        pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.custom-properties+xml"
        pkg:padding="256">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <Properties
                xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties"
                xmlns:vt="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/docPropsVTypes">
                <property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="3"
                    name="Telephone number">
                    <vt:lpwstr>555-555-5555</vt:lpwstr>
                </property>
            </Properties>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
```

Assuming that you declare the namespace with the prefix "prop" in your stylesheet like this:

```
xmlns:prop="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties"
```

if you save as a single XML file, you can locate them with the following XPath:

```
pkg:package/pkg:part/pkg:xmlData/prop:Properties
```

and you could create a template match like this:

```
<xsl:template match="prop:Properties">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```